# Execute JavaScript using IText

Tags: javascript, java, pdf, itext, xfa

I have a dynamic pdf file which needs to be filled programmatically. I am using `itext` libraries to do so. Below are the steps I followed.

1. Extract the dynamic pdf and get the data xml file.
2. Fill the xml data file.
3. Call the itext apis to generate new pdf by passing the template pdf and xml data file.

The issue I face is if there is a repeater inside the container (which has a close button) in the template pdf, its not copied into the generated interactive pdf file. None of the javascript functionalities are triggered when creating the new pdf and because of which some of the fields become read only.

Is it possible to trigger the javascript in the pdf while generating the new pdf or while opening the new pdf?

Much appreciate any help.

Comment: *"Is it possible to trigger the javascript in the pdf while generating the new pdf"* - no. At least not out-of-the-box, iText does not execute JavaScript, so you'd have to provide a JavaScript interpreter and the adobe object model. But even then triggering the JavaScript might fail as you don't enter data manually, so you don't change e.g. focus which might be what your JavaScript looks for.

Comment: that been said your issue might be different still, ite might be related to broken usage rights signatures. As you neither show your pivotal code nor share the pdf before and after, there is nothing for us to look into.

Comment: Thanks mkl. Here is the code wich I used to create the pdf where  src --> default template pdf  file , xmlData --> xml data file , dest --> the newly created pdf  manipulatePdf(String src, String xmlData, String dest) throws IOException, DocumentException { 
  
  PdfAction action = new PdfAction();
  
  PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(src);
  PdfStamper stamper = new PdfStamper(reader, new FileOutputStream(dest),'\0', true); 
  AcroFields form = stamper.getAcroFields();  
  XfaForm xfa = form.getXfa();
  xfa.fillXfaForm(new FileInputStream(xmlData));
  
  stamper.close();
  
 }

Comment: The xml data file is created by extracting the xml structure of template pdf file using tansform() of Transformer. The <xfa:data> is taken to a different xml file to populate the data.In the pdf file , there are some fields which will be populated based on a radio button selection ( which is hidden initially) , even if I set the correct value in the xml file , the fields are not shown in the the output pdf. Hope you understand my question.

Comment: If you only have to fill one file template (or only a very few templates) but that fairly often, you might want to consider analysing the contained JavaScript and implement equivalent behaviour in your java code manipulating the XFA xml. That being said, XFA has anyways been deprecated, so its dying out has already started.

Comment: Is there any way we can achieve this functionality other than iText? I have n number of template files.  How can we do it in the javacode by manipulating the XFA file?

Comment: well, you might want to look for adobe products. I doubt you will find complete XFA support in products elsewhere.